# Ion Auth check login from MY_Loader class

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

This may be a basic Codeigniter (or php) question, but I'm trying to check if a user is logged in with Ion Auth for every page call so I can provide a 'Sign-in' or 'Sign-out' link.

I have my header, content, and footer views loading from MY_Loader class and was trying to use `$this->ion_auth->logged_in()` to check if a user is logged in, but I get this php error,

> PHP Error: Undefined property: MY_Loader::$ion_auth

Here is MY_Loader.php:

```
<?php

/**
 * /application/core/MY_Loader.php
 *
 */
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader {
    public function template_main($template_name, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
    {
        $vars['signin'] = $this->ion_auth->logged_in() ? 'signout' : 'signin';
        $vars['signin_text'] = $this->ion_auth->logged_in() ? 'Sign-out' : 'Sign-in';
        $content  = $this->view('frontend/main_template/header', $vars, $return);
        $content .= $this->view($template_name, $vars, $return);
        $content .= $this->view('frontend/main_template/footer', $vars, $return);

        if ($return)
        {
            return $content;
        }
    }
}

/* End of MY_Loader.php */
/* Location: ./application/core/MY_Loader.php */
```

I am autoloading the ion_auth library. How can I call the logged-in() function in MY_Loader class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The autoloaded files probably haven't been loaded yet.  Add $this->load->library('ion_auth') to the top of the method.

Comment: I thought of that. It then gives me another error: `Undefined property: MY_Loader::$load`

Comment: Okay, think I figured it out. Instead of using $this, I created a new object variable `$ia = new ion_auth();` then used `$ia->ion_auth->logged_in()` . This worked as expected. Perhaps someone can explain why this is needed for Codeignitor.

Comment: Try this instead:

    $ci =& get_instance();
    $ci->ion_auth->logged_in();

Comment: Yes, that works as well. Guess its better to grab an instance of an existing object than creating a new one. Thanks Ben.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I misread the question, so sorry. But I'm leaving the answer up for future readers that might find it useful. Try using a hook to solve your problem.

My suggestion is to simply check if the user is logged in from your controller's constructor method and save the result to a class variable.

```
$this->user_logged_in = (bool)$this->ion_auth->logged_in();
```

This would let you make the call once for each controller, instead of once for each view (easier to maintain, and keeping basic ACL/logic out of the view). Then all you need to do is pass the variable to your view.

```
$data['user_logged_in'] = $this->user_logged_in;
$this->load->view('view_file_name', $data);
```

What I like to do when I want the entire app to require a login is to call these types of checks via CodeIgniter's [hooks](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html). In this case, maybe the `post_controller_constructor` hook, this way it's called automatically (just make sure to filter out the pages you want to ignore this check, i.e.. login & register, etc).